# What is a word/idiom for 'unable to decide'?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Let's say I have an important decision to make and I can't decide between two competing things (like break up with a girl or not break up with her). What would be a word/idiom to express that?

Comment: You've got a lot of nice suggestions here.  I think it is important to note that some of them have very different connotations.  For example, *vacillating* and *waffling* imply that you keep flipping back and forth between the choices; *quandary* and *dilemma* imply that the choice is extremely difficult (and usually all available options are painful or costly); *ambivalence* means having both positive and negative feelings about a *single* person or thing (rather than having difficulty deciding between two competing options).

Comment: I believe his decision, and the fact he said that he couldn't decide, inherently makes it an extremely difficult decision for him.  I agree with your comments about the other choices, but I still believe his position as he described it falls nicely under the term quandary.

Comment: I used to be indecisive, but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here are several choices: **on the fence**, **indecisive**, **vacillating**.  I would use each one a little differently in a sentence.

> I am still **on the fence** about breaking up with her.

or

> I am **indecisive** about breaking up with her.

or

> I am **vacillating** between breaking up or staying with her.

Comment: I think "undecided" would fit better in the second instance, since it's a specific case.  I'd use "indecisive" to describe someone who is unable to decide on things in general, not just about one particular thing.

Comment: Maybe you could vacillate her while you decide.

Comment: I don't like *indecisive* at all.

Answer (score 23):

What about this?

> I am **torn between** breaking up or staying with her.

Answer (score 15):

In this case, you can say one of the following.

> I am *undecided* about breaking up with her.
>
> I am *in two minds* about breaking up with her. (BrE)
>
> I am *of two minds* about breaking up with her. (AmE)

Comment: Would your second example be "I am of two minds..."?

Comment: You get +1 for 'undecided', it's actually quite amusing that none else suggested it :-) Plain words are normally the best -- pick the Attic over the Asiatic. This is especially true concerning recommendations to non-native speakers (not sure if the includes the OP).

Answer (score 15):

You have a *dilemma*, and you might even be *on the horns of a dilemma* if you want to be a little more fancy about it.

Comment: @alexg Just curious, how do you decide if "horns" is approperiate? Is it arbitary? Like e.g. is "spikes" less approperiate than "horns"? Or is this a fixed phrase?

Comment: It has to be horns. The phrase can be traced to medieval Latin *argumentum cornutum* or *syllogismus cornutus*, where the image is that the problem is like a charging bull where you can avoid one horn only to be gored by the other.

Answer (score 11):

I would say that you have a "quandary" on your hands - which means a difficult situation!

Answer (score 11):

If the reason for lack of a final decision is that you keep switching between the two choices, you can say you're [**ambivalent**.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalence)

If you aren't managing to endorse one decision or the other even briefly, you're [**undecided**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undecided) - or maybe you could say the matter is still [**in abeyance**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abeyance) (because you're not dealing with it).

Comment: *Ambivalence* can apply in this situation (he could be feeling ambivalent toward his girlfriend, if he's not sure whether to break up with her), but I would not say it means switching back and forth.

Comment: @John Y: Well the origin is Latin *ambo*:both + *valentia*:strength. Leading to the standard meaning of being [unstably] caught between conflicting urges of equal force. If you understand the word differently I can't do much about that. To *feel ambivalent towards someone* is a colloquialism meaning you can't decide if you're positively or negatively disposed toward them. Because you have both reactions equally strongly, and keep switching between them.

Comment: The **primary** implication of *ambivalence* is the two conflicting feelings, not whether you flip between them.  Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, Wikipedia, and my own experience indicate that these opposing feelings are *simultaneous*, though M-W does give as its second definition (2a) "continual fluctuation". You keep using the phrase "standard meaning" as if there is some ultimate authority, but you never give any citations.

Comment: @John Y: I think we've reached the limits of my ability to discern fine conceptual/cognitive distinctions. I don't know any other way to *have* conflicting feelings, without "flipping between them". I only have one conciousness, and at any given instant it would either be in one of the conflicting states, or thinking of something else, and thus not aware of either. I wrote [unstably] indicating that aspect might or might not apply. You agree M-W gives 'fluctuation' as a connotation, but your first comment ruled against "switching back and forth". Which is all I'm defending.

Comment: But your answer says *ambivalence* is flipping between two *choices*.  Let me make it simple for you:  Someone can truthfully answer "yes" to both the following questions:  *Do you love your mother?* and *Do you hate your mother?*  This is *ambivalence* toward the mother.  If someone says *I'll have the chocolate ice cream*, quickly followed by *No, wait, I'll have the vanilla instead*, possibly followed then by *No, sorry, give me the chocolate; for real this time*:  That is *waffling* or *vacillation* between chocolate and vanilla.

Comment: I think your example is contrived. *Ambivalence* in that usage is simply fudging the issue that *at any given moment* you may fall strongly one side or the other. Not that you walk around all day wrestling with a decision about which side to commit to and act in accordance with. Which is OP's context, implying continual flux, for which I'm happy with *ambivalent*.

Answer (score 11):

You can also be "at sixes and sevens." (Slightly BE)

Comment: Isn't this actually an example of Cockney Rhyming Slang?

Answer (score 11):

I would say that you are *conflicted*.

Answer (score 8):

Trying not to repeat other answers:

You may be *waffling* (if you find yourself deciding and then changing your mind), or you may be *wrestling with a {decision, dilemma, quandry}*.

Comment: I've never come across that usage of *waffle* before. And after a quick search, the only place I find it on the internet is [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waffle) Wiktionary entry which also gives the unusual meaning *wave/waft* [a hand]. Do you really use it for *vacilating*? It's not a widespread usage, I feel.

Comment: "Waffling" is extremely common in US political analysis. Politicians waffle between positions. It's highly uncommon in general parlance for everyday situations, e.g., "Forced to choose between scrambled eggs and waffles, he waffled." You just don't see that.

Comment: *Waffling* has a entirely different meaning. Politicians waffle, but to do so means to speak without coming to the point.

Comment: I can see how the standard meaning of *refuse to be clear about intentions* could morph into *be unable to decide one's intentions*. I just didn't realise it had already done so. Now we can assume *waffling politicians* are just being honest when they won't say what they think - it's because they don't actually know what they think in the first place!

Comment: Interesting.  I've heard things like "I'm waffling between Subway and Burger King" in casual conversation a lot.  The political application is much newer in my experience.  Maybe I have unusual friends? :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: From Merriam-Webster: intransitive verb 1
: equivocate, vacillate <waffled on the important issues>; also : yo-yo, flip-flop

Comment: +1 - Easily the best answer here (aside from mine of course).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You **really** never heard that before? I guess you don't pay much attention to USA politics. In 2004 GWB said of his Democratic opponent "He waffles so much, he'd turn the White House into The Waffle House". This was in reference to cloture votes Senator Kerry took on things he later voted against. Then GWB partisans proceeded throw frozen waffles at his opponent's public events (GWB didn't hold public events). Now nearly a decade later, they are still trying to unload all the T-Shirts they made up. See http://www.cafepress.com/rightthings/402171

Comment: @T.E.D. To be honest I don't pay *that* much attention to the US politic *process* - just the end results. Also most of my input comes from Brit media. But if I *had* read your example I'd probably have assumed it meant "witters on inconclusively/evasively" rather than "actually votes inconsistently". But as I said, I see how the meaning shift would arise. It certainly hasn't made it into standard UK speech yet, though. When it does, I may be one of the first to understand the usage! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, after checking in on it myself yesterday, I have to say I envy you. Ick.

Answer (score 8):

My favorite word for this is `dithering`.

This implies a person is going back and forth between two or more possible decisions, but can never settle on one. A person who is described this way is by implication a rather flighty individual.

This is similar to Monica Cellio's `waffling`. The main difference is that someone who is waffling is by implication a really bad leader. In other words, both words are a bit pejorative, but you are better off to use `dithering` for someone whose indecision primarily affects themselves, and `waffling` for someone whose indecision primarily affects others.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the potential modes of revenge of said girlfriend, you could be *caught between Scylla and Charybdis* or trying to decide between two equally unattractive options that will result in death.

Comment: I like the Greek mythology, and that you mention death as a consequence.  Break up with the girlfriend and die shortly thereafter in a bloodbath?  Or stay with her and die a slow, lingering death? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Stymied.

"Dude, what's wrong with you? Decide!"

"Can't. Stymied."

You are then left alone, to be stymied is to be uncomfortably unable to decide.

Comment: That's not what the word means. To be stymied is to be stuck or hindered by some sort of obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no-one has mentioned swithering. To swither between two options means to be unable to make a decision between then.

Answer (score 0):

The word that springs to my mind is to *procrastinate*. When I'm stuck deciding on what course of action to take, I can often get nothing achieved because I'm too busy *procrastinating*.