# Idioms that mean making decision between two good options

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for expressions that mean "to decide between two good options." For example, you have to choose between getting a car that you like or a super car that's very expensive but you are not sure if you like it.

I searched on Google and there are some phrases that mean to make decision between two **unpleasant** options so, I am not sure if there such an expression in English or not.

Comment: If you take forever, you're a [Buridan's ass](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/86902/300).

Comment: "A super car that's very expensive but you are not sure if you like it" - it's not clear how this is a good option. Are you looking for an idiom that means making a decision between two potentially good options but you're not sure whether they're actually good?

Comment: @LarsH I think they're getting the car for free. In that sense, expensive is a good thing, while he may not like it. On the other hand, the cheap car is a waste because he's getting it free, but he knows he likes it

Comment: A closely related phrase is the economic concept of "opportunity cost".

Answer (score 32):

Not quite the noun you are after, but another way to express the situation is to say that you are *spoilt for choice*

Comment: Apparently a British idiom; not common in the US.

Comment: I know the idiom well, but still sounds like you do not need to choose

Comment: ***spoiled*** *for choice* is the American version.

Comment: I've never heard or seen it, no matter which way you spell it.

Comment: Ngram has both version rapidly gaining in popularity since around 1970.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoiled+for+choice%2C+spoilt+for+choice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoiled%20for%20choice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoilt%20for%20choice%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 17):

How about *an embarrassment of riches*?

Comment: In a similar vein, The rich get richer.

Comment: Also sounds like you do not need to choose

Answer (score 16):

This is an **[approach-approach conflict](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/approach-approach%20conflict)**:

> a psychological conflict that results when a choice must be made between two desirable alternatives

Best [illustrated by Rebecca Black](https://funnyordie.com/2011/03/31/23678/which-seat-should-i-take-w-rebecca-black/):

Front seat or back seat? Which one should I take?

As you note, the more common conflict is the "avoid-avoid conflict" where you must choose the less bad of two bad alternatives, and the "approach-avoid conflict", where there are simultaneously good and bad aspects to the conflict.

The psychological condition of having too many good alternatives to choose from and no ability to decide which is best so you choose none of them is **option block**, coined by Douglas Coupland in the novel "Microserfs", though that doesn't seem to have caught on. **[Overchoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overchoice)** is another option, coined in 1970:

> When confronted with a plethora of choices without perfect information, many people prefer to make no choice at all, even if making a choice would lead to a better outcome.

Comment: Sounds like a winner although I have never heard of it

Comment: Your killing me +1 for Rebecca Black reference.

Comment: @Emmentaler: We so excited!

Comment: I would argue that 'approach-approach conflict' is an idiom, and that overchoice is too ambiguous to apply.

Answer (score 12):

A win-win situation comes to mind

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/win-win)

> (of a situation or outcome) That benefits both or all parties, **or that has two distinct benefits**.

That said, you do not choose one of them but get both.

Comment: No, that refers to two people both winning from a single agreement between them.

Comment: That is not true. It does not have to be an agreement between people. If I sell something that takes up too much room and I get a good price, I get more space and have cash. That is also a win-win situation

Comment: So I disagree and get downvoted

Comment: What are the two good options here?

Comment: I think the O.P. is describing something that's more like a [**no-lose situation**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-lose), which is not quite synonymous with win-win. (It's hard to say for sure, though, because I find the car example a little confusing.)

Comment: The FEEL of the question is a little you are blessed if you do and blessed if you don't ;) or perhaps not

Comment: mplungjan: while you’re right that it needn’t be just an agreement between people, I think @mjkrebbs is right that *win-win situation* doesn’t fit this question. A win-win situation is where some *single* option is good in multiple ways (especially, in ways that one might have expected to be in conflict).  This question asks for something where *multiple options* are under consideration.

Comment: @mp - I agree. I think "blessed if you do and blessed if you do" is _no-lose_, because you have two options, and you're blessed either way. But I think "win-win" is more like you're doubly blessed for a single course of action, like selling that bulky piece of furniture, thereby getting money and extra room.

Comment: So should I delete my answer? It WAS the first thing that came to mind but I think OP is looking for a dilemma type expression

Comment: Don't delete it, it's a helpful answer but do change the spelling of wictionary. I thought to myself, "Hello. A new witchcraft dictionary!?" :)

Comment: A win-win situation is one in which a single choice provides multiple benefits. It is not a dilemma between two good choices. **If the choices turn out not to be mutually exclusive** then it can be a win-win situation.

Answer (score 10):

How about a **delightful dilemma**?

Answer (score 6):

I've heard (and used) the phrase "positive dilemma". Some may say this is an oxymoron, as a dilemma is by definition between two negative options. But while the word dilemma is *especially* used to describe multiple undesirable choices, it can simply be a choice between multiple options or a difficult problem. ([Source.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dilemma))

I also like the phrase "to be faced with a wealth of options", although perhaps this isn't specific enough.

Because of the use of ["win-win" in game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win-win_game), I'd suggest this implies something that's positive for multiple people, rather than a choice with multiple positive options, although I'm sure anyone would understand what you mean.

Comment: I see no reason to load the dilemma with negative connotation. I also read http://www.merriam-webster.com: `Buridan's ass` is `a hypothetical **dilemma** in which a person is postulated as presented with **two equally attractive and attainable alternatives** and therefore loses freedom of choice`

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that we haven't seen this one:

> [Six of one, and a half dozen of the other](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/six+of+one+and+half+a+dozen+of+the+other)

Refers to there being a choice between two alternatives, and the choice doesn't really matter.

Comment: Not really a choice. It's more like apportion of blame. A typical example is a squabble between 2 parties, and the adjudicator declares it is six of one and half a dozen of the other (e.g. a mother to her sons).

Comment: That's one use, however it is also used with respect to two choices that are functionally similar

Comment: Your citing a source that cites a book that doesn't cite any actual source*. This could just be 1 person's interpretation of this idiom. If you could quote something more official? * http://www.amazon.com/review/RM4TTH74NNYAV/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#RM4TTH74NNYAV

Comment: This expression is widely used in the U.S. (by my generation, anyway), but its point is the functional similarity of the options, to pick up C dawg's expression. Both options might be positive, both might be negative, both might be so-so.

Answer (score 3):

It makes me think of "First World problems," although that may not be specific as you want. Related to that is the possibly offensive and probably only applicable in the US "white people problems."

Comment: The thing about a first world problem though is that it is a legitimate problem. Not being able to find a nearby parking spot when going to the opera is a first world problem, but it's still a problem.

Comment: @EricLippert, if thats the case then I see it get misused alot.

Comment: “Champagne problems” means the same without potential offense.

Answer (score 2):

How about "there are no wrong choices".

Answer (score 1):

A "no-lose decision" seems much closer than some other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the phrase

> **[analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis)**

or

> **[the paradox of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paradox_of_Choice)**

both of which are drawn from psycholgy rather than common idiomatic English. Both colorfully describe the experience of impaired decision-making when presented with *too many* good options.

**Analysis paralysis** is an unwillingness to commit to a course of action without being totally certain that you're making the best choice.

**The paradox of choice** refers to decreased satisfaction dervied from a given choice in the face of a large number of alternatives.

Related terms are **[decision fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_fatigue)**, **[ego depletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_depletion)**, and **[choice](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/emir.kamenica/documents/simplicitySeeking.pdf) [proliferation](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/soups14-paper-korff.pdf)**.

Answer (score 0):

How about "decide the bestest between two bests" as opposed to "choosing lesser evil between two evils"? In Japanese, we say －どっちに転んでも損しない - You don't lose whichever side you tumble down.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to express it is  " It's a hard one to call "

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have the two good choices - pick up the red pen or the blue pen. You equally love both, but problem is you have the option to choose any one of them.
I will say it this way - 
"I am torn between the red and blue one, and hence I'm unsure what to go for as I love the red one, and the blue one for that matter."

This is just my idea. Though it's not a idiom. But just a thought to share with.
Comments please.

Answer (score -6):

How about

> It's safe to say that **I'm between thighs** on that one.

Seems legitimate.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that expression or cite examples?  I've never heard that one . . .

Comment: You got that right, Mr_Spock, except the OP is looking for an idiom, not a neologism. Also, it helps if your neologism is universally understood, which the hanger comment is not, babe. ;-)  +1 for the "toots", I like that!

Comment: @KristinaLopez You want a neologism that is likely to be understood: how about "stuck between a pillow and a soft place".

Comment: I got **that** one @Kaz, and the one about the thighs, too. ;-) It was the hanger comment that confused me, unless Mr_Spock was implying I am a stuffed shirt.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Between thighs is quite illogical. When you're between thighs, you aren't vaccillating between which thigh you choose; you're single-mindedly going for the middle.