# Alternative to "Dilemma"

Tags: single-word-requests

Often "dilemma" is used to describe a situation of  choosing between two undesirable alternatives, or two unpleasant choices. I am interested in a situation where there are sharply conflicting two answers for a (scientific) question, there are good reasons to doubt each of the two answers, but otherwise, each answer, if correct, will be fruitful and "good." Is using "dilemma" to describe such a situation appropriate (and not confusing)? Is there an alternative word?

Comment: I think terms along the line of "happy dilemma" are sometimes used to describe a choice between two good options.

Comment: It probably wouldn't usually be used when there are only *two* [desirable] alternatives, but [***spoilt for choice***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+spoilt+for+choice) is a common idiomatic usage. Many if not most written contexts involving [both "**dilemma**" and "**spoilt for choice**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dilemma%22+%22spoilt+for+choice%22) in close proximity are clearly using both expressions to describe the same "difficult" choice. (By implication, ***dilemma*** doesn't *always* imply "between undesirable alternatives.)

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks. You could also say "fortuitous dilemma," which is more to the point, but "happy dilemma" does sound a lot better. "Spoilt for choice" is cute but it kind of implies that there are more choices than just two.

Comment: @Ricky: Each to their own, I guess. But to me, a "fortuitous dilemma" would suggest a situation where one *unexpectedly* (by chance rather than intention) found oneself in the position of being able to make a choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not sure what you're objecting to. Isn't what you've just described exactly what the OP meant? Please clarify.

Comment: *open question*?  *unsettled*?

Comment: Yes, it refers to an open unsettled question. Each solution, if correct, will lead to important fruits. Of course, some people have a strong view about one of the two options prevailing.

Comment: This question, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139404/idioms-that-mean-making-decision-between-two-good-options covers some of the same ground. I wouldn't call it a duplicate because it requests an idiom, rather than a single word.

Comment: Let me mention that it is not that we have two good options to choose from but that we have too possible options, where only one is the correct one.  Each option may be "good" in its consequence but also there are reasons to be uncomfortable with each one being the correct one.

Comment: @Ricky: I mean if someone was in a *fortuitous dilemma* that would suggest to me that *by happenstance* he found himself in a dilemma. Describing something as *fortuitous* usually implies *by **good** luck*, so in this context I suppose that would have to further imply it's "good" to be in that particular dilemma. Leading even further to the implication that all available choices must be favourable, since there's no other obvious explanation for why you'd want to be in that dilemma. But it just seems a bit tortuous to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"quandary"** is not exactly the same as **"dilemma"** but their meanings sometimes overlap.

> **"quandary"** - a state of perplexity or doubt, a situation in which you are confused about what to do. [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quandary)
>
> - The unexpected results of the test have created a quandary for researchers.
> - I'm in a quandary about whether I should try to repair my stereo or buy a new one, even though I don't have the money to do either.
> - Williams's quandary is not unlike that faced by other urban executives who have had to wrestle with a deeply rooted power structure.

If you’re uncertain what to do because all of your options seem unpleasant, you’re probably in a quandary. Some voters find themselves in a quandary when they dislike all of the candidates. A more common quandary is when you plan two events at the same time and can’t decide which one to attend. Some synonyms are predicament, **dilemma**, plight, and pickle — and choosing which word to use is a quandary in itself. [**vocabulary.com**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/quandary)