# Idiom for choosing between two generally alike things that are dissimilar in their details

Tags: idiom-requests

I am confused because I don't seem to find the right idiom, for example:

> I have to choose between two things that are generally alike but
>   dissimilar with respect to details.
>
> I have to choose between two scientists (they are alike as they are
>   both scientists) that worked on 2 different topics (thus making them
>   dissimilar).

Which idiom do I use?
What I am looking for is an **idiom** that is the **exact** **opposite** of **"between the devil and the deep sea."**

It was on the tip of my tongue. Please help.

Comment: Related: [Is there a word to describe indecisiveness between two things?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86760/is-there-a-word-to-describe-indecisiveness-between-two-things) and [What is a word/idiom for 'unable to decide'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33914/what-is-a-word-idiom-for-unable-to-decide). "To be torn between two things" is the option I like the best.

Comment: The metaphor depends on whether or not their attributes are similar in all the important matters, but differ in inconsequential or unanticipated ways, or if the differences merit distinction.

Answer (score 2):

> What I am looking for is an idiom that is the exact opposite of ***"between the devil and the deep sea."***

That means, you are ***[spoilt for choices](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-spoilt-for-choice)***

> to be ​unable to ​choose because there are so many ​possible good ​choices

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online]

Comment: Good one!  The version I know/use is *spoilt for choice*.

Comment: or  *an embarrassment of riches*